# I have a problem that "@IsNotEmpty" in Dto does not check empty

Tags: api, nestjs, schema, decorator, dto

I am building a project using NestJs. I have a problem that "@IsNotEmpty" in Dto does not check empty. The checking is only performed because {require: true} in the schema. Please help me with this case. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```js
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class AddCommentDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    comment: string

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    walletId: string

    @IsString()
    replyCommentId: string
}

//Schema
@Schema({
    timestamps: true,
})
export class UserComment extends Document {
    @Prop({ 
        required: true
    })
    walletId: string;

    @Prop({
    })
    replyCommentId: string;

    @Prop({ 
        require: true
    })
    comment: string;
}
```

An explanation for this case.

Comment: and have you initialized `ValidationPipe` in main?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the problem as your suggestion.